# Precision of solutions given condition number of matrix (floating point)

Tags: matrix, floating-point-precision

I have a question on which I am stuck. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

[image: 1]

I did poorly on my last midterm with a question similar to this one so I'd like to be able to understand the concept in addition to help towards the answer so that I can do better on the final exam.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to error analysis of linear systems is to consider that the given system represents any of the systems

> (A + ΔA) * (x + Δx) = b + Δb

where ΔA and Δb have entries of relative size μ = 5 * 10<sup>-d</sup>, so that

> ||ΔA|| ∼ μ * ||A|| and ||Δb|| ∼ μ * ||b||.

The idea being that the solution found will represent the exact solution of a perturbed system with perturbations in the bounds given.

---

By standard manipulations of truncated geometric or Neumann series

> (A + ΔA) * Δx = Δb - ΔA * x

and ignoring all second order terms,

> Δx ≃ A<sup>-1</sup> * Δb - A<sup>-1</sup> * ΔA * x = A<sup>-1</sup> * Δb - A<sup>-1</sup> * ΔA * A<sup>-1</sup> * b

so that

> ||Δx|| ≃ ||A<sup>-1</sup>|| * ||Δb|| + ||A<sup>-1</sup>|| * ||ΔA|| * ||x|| ≦ μ * (||A<sup>-1</sup>|| * ||b|| + κ * ||x||)
>
> ||Δx|| ≦ 2 * μ * κ * ||x||

The relative error of x, ||Δx||/||x||, which will determine the number of valid digits in x, is about or smaller than 2 * μ *  κ. Per assignment, this has to be smaller than 5 * 10<sup>-e</sup>, or

> 2 * κ ≦ 10<sup>d-e</sup>.

and with the specific formula for κ,

> 2 * λ * n<sup>α</sup> ≦ 10<sup>d-e</sup>.